# Overriding MemberPress Template Files in Oxygen Builder via Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, memberpress

I want to override the MemberPress plugin's templates by following

https://docs.memberpress.com/article/165-how-to-override-template-files

But the problem is that I'm using [Oxygen Builder](https://oxygenbuilder.com/) which disables the WordPress themes so I can't copy the template folder to my child theme.

Is there a filter to change the MemberPress plugin template override path so I can override the templates from within a custom functionality plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom WordPress plugin to solve this problem.

This plugin is made for Oxygen Builder users where the theme is completely disabled. Simply add your customized MemberPress template files inside the [mepr_templates] directory in this plugin.

You can find the plugin here
https://github.com/Taimurian/oxygen-memberpress-support